# yii2, оптимизация запросов в БД, связанные модели

Tags: php, yii2

Я создал данный запрос для получения данных с помощью "связывания моделей"

мой контроллер

```
\Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
            'name' => 'description',
            'content' => "Freedom Home. " . self::META
        ]);

        $model = new Search();
        $dataProvider = $model->historis();

        \Yii::$app->getView()->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/js/history.js', ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END, 'depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
        $this->getView()->registerCssFile("@web/css/index.css", ['depends' => ['frontend\assets\AppAsset']]);
        $this->getView()->registerCssFile("@web/css/post.css", ['depends' => ['frontend\assets\AppAsset']]);

        return $this->render('index', array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
        ));
```

```
public function historis()
    {
        $query = History::find()
            ->select(['history.id', 'history.title', 'history.user_id', 'history.description', 'history.datetime'])
            ->joinWith('user')
            ->joinWith('historyHashtags');

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => [
                    'id' => SORT_DESC
                ]
            ],
        ]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

метод getUser()

```
/**
     * Gets query for [[User]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])->select(['id', 'username']);
    }
```

historyHashtags

```
    public function getHistoryHashtags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(HistoryHashtags::className(), ['history_id' => 'id'])->select(['hashtag_id', 'history_id'])->joinWith('hashtag');
    }
```

метод getHashtag

```
    public function getHashtag()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Hashtags::className(), ['id' => 'hashtag_id'])->select(['id', 'name']);
    }
```

В итоге я получаю целых 14 запросов в БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос как можно оптимизировать данный код?

1. Убрать запросы типу SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM и SELECT * FROM `information_schema`
2. Оптимизировать мой код чтобы он сделал меньше запросов(Если это возможно)

Comment: 1. Немного смутило то, что почему-то самый большой (из показанных) запросов - это к таблице user, хотя 2 мс не является чем-то критичным. Просто обратил внимание.

2. Полученные данные, как я понимаю, потом передаются в какой-нибудь GridView, так? Если так, и ЕСЛИ ЗАПИСЕЙ НЕ ТАК МНОГО, то попробуйте ActiveDataProvider заменить на ArrayDataProvider. У меня на небольших выборках он быстрей.

Comment: не надо убирать запросы вида show и information_schema, они выполняются в дебаг режиме приложения, чтобы код всегда знал актуальную структуру БД. в продакшене структура моделей будет кеширована и запросов этих не будет.

Comment: @ДенисСепетов Ну это на данном этапе разработки мало, но если будет около 10 000 записей то оставить ActiveDataProvider лучше?
Вопрос по коду что все написано корректно? И возможности оптимизации нету?
Логика что у меня таблица users, history, hasthags. И связная таблица между history и hashtags history_hashtags, чтобы знать какие хештеги привязаны к таблицам

Возможно сделал плохо структуру БД но других вариантов не вижу

Comment: @DenysMaksiura 10 тысяч записей - это да, для ArrayDataProvider слишком много. Лучше оставить ActiveDataProvider. По коду вопросов нет - это не такая сложная концепция. Увы, я не дам отличного совета :-(